# Information Popup in Mac

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am developing an application for Mac OS , i need to display a information popup in Mac, In Windows OS context, it should be similar to the one, which used to be displayed near by tray-icon,

More real example is, assuming any messenger application is running, and someone form your contact list became online/available,then Messenger App display a Animated Popup near by tray-icon area,

the same use-case i am having , 
While googling i came to know, either i can make use of NSAlert or Growl , any other application that i should think.

Comment: Rohan, if my answer has satisfied your question, just make sure to mark it as the correct answer... ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is no default alternatives to the Windows popup message on the Mac, but the de facto standard for doing this is through Growl. `NSAlert` popup messages are usually used to display exactly those: alerts. They are often to large and cumbersome to display small amounts of information well without distracting or interrupting the user. Growl, on the other hand, works well for things like these, and is what you should use.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, if i go with Growl SDK, does that machine on the target machine Growl should be installed

Comment: Yes Rohan, the user has to install Growl. Depending on the target audience of your app though, Growl might be there already. Just about every Mac user I know who uses IM has picked it up through Adium.

Comment: There is also a growl with-installer version which you can use to present the same functionality as Adium, giving the user the chance to install it while installing your own app.

Comment: If the alerts are important, you'll probably want to have a backup alert system in addition to Growl, as not all users have Growl installed, and even those that do can elect to disable notifications from your app.

Comment: Hi mipadi, what backup alert system can you suggest?